# Hello I am trying to write a method that duplicates all vowels but only if they are on their own. for example "beautiful" would return "beautiifuul"

Tags: java

Here's what I have if someone could give me some idea of what to do that would be great. I think taking the index and counting how many values are together would be helpful but im not sure how to implement that. isVowel is a helper method to determine if the char is a vowel.

```
public static String doubleVowelsMaybe(String s) 
{  
    int run =0;
    String n = "";
    for(int i = 0; i< s.length(); ++i)
    {
        char k = s.charAt(i);
        if(isVowel(k))
        {
            
        }
        if(run == 1)
        {
            n = n + s.substring(i, i+1) + s.substring(i, i+1);
            run=0;
        }
        else
        {
            n = n + s.substring(i, i+1);
            run= 0;
        }
    }
    
    return n;
```

Comment: You can iterate over the string and for every letter check `!isVowel(s[i - 1]) && isVowel(s[i]) && !isVowel(s[i])` which means letter is vowel and surrounded by consonants. In such case you insert two letters

Comment: What about a word that starts with a vowel, like _upstart_? Would that become **uupstaart** ? Similarly if a word ends in a vowel, like _villa_. Would that become **viillaa** ?

Answer (score 3):

Most simple string manipulation tasks like this can be fairly easily done with a [regex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). This one's a one-liner:

```java
public static String doubleVowelsMaybe(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("(?<![aeiou])([aeiou])(?![aeiou])", "$1$1");
}
```

The regex works as follows:

- `(?<![aeiou])` is a negative lookbehind, so it matches only if the character is not preceded by a vowel.
- `([aeiou])` matches a single vowel, and captures it to group number 1.
- `(?![aeiou])` is a negative lookahead, so it matches only if the character is not followed by a vowel.
- The replacement of `$1$1` means two copies of whatever was matched by group number 1, which is the single vowel character.

Comment: Would it make a difference to use `[^aeiou]([aeiou])[^aeiou]` ?

Comment: @Abra Yes, that would make two differences. Firstly, it would replace three characters instead of one, because the first and last character classes are included in the part of the string which will be substituted. Secondly, it would fail to match solitary vowels at the start or end of the input string. You could solve both issues by doing something like `s.replaceAll("([^aeiou]|^)([aeiou])([^aeiou]|$)", "$1$2$2$3")` to also allow the vowel to be preceded by the start of the string `^` or the end of the string `$`, and to keep the extra parts of the match in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String abc = "beautiful";
        String n = "";
        int i = 0;
        char[] abcchar = abc.toCharArray();
        HashSet<Character> hs = new HashSet<>();
        hs.add('a');
        hs.add('e');
        hs.add('i');
        hs.add('o');
        hs.add('u');
        while (i < abcchar.length) {
            if (i + 1 < abcchar.length && hs.contains(abcchar[i]) && !hs.contains(abcchar[i + 1])) {
                n = n + abc.substring(i, i + 1) + abc.substring(i, i + 1);
            } else {

                while (hs.contains(abcchar[i])) {
                    n = n + abc.substring(i, i + 1);
                    i++;
                }
                n = n + abc.substring(i, i + 1);
            }
            i++;
        }
        System.out.print(n);
    }
}
```